# Can't create UniswapV2Pair from constructor on Ethereum Mainnet

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-deployment, uniswap, constructor

### I want to create a Uniswap Pair in a `constructor()` block of my token smart-contract.

However, when I try to do this, I get `"error":"execution reverted"`.

---

Perhaps these nuances will help you understand what the problem is:

- If the line with the initialization of the pair (`_pair = IPan...`) is commented out - code works properly.
- This problem does not arise if the contract is deployed to Goerli, which have the same UniswapV2Router address as Mainnet. Issues occur only when i try to deploy it on Ethereum Mainnet.
- Also, the contract is successfully deployed on the local blockchain. No errors after compilation.

Here is the address of the UniswapV2Router that I used
`0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D`

Below is the code related directly to the interaction with Uniswap.

```js
interface IPancakeFactory {
    function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair);
}

interface IPancakePair {
    function token0() external view returns (address);
    function token1() external view returns (address);
    function getReserves() external view returns (uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1, uint32 blockTimestampLast);
}

interface IPancakeRouter01 {
    function factory() external pure returns (address);
    function WETH() external pure returns (address);
}

interface IPancakeRouter02 is IPancakeRouter01 {}

contract MyTokenContract is Context, Ownable, IERC20 {

  IPancakeRouter02 internal _router;
  IPancakePair internal _pair;

  constructor(address _routerAddress) {
          _router = IPancakeRouter02(_routerAddress);
          _pair = IPancakePair(IPancakeFactory(_router.factory()).createPair(address(this), _router.WETH()));
        
          _balances[owner()] = _totalSupply;
          emit Transfer(address(0), owner(), _totalSupply);
    }
}
```

It turns out that I simply cannot deploy a contract if a new pair is created in the constructor()

***UPD:*** After a more detailed breakdown of the code into simple operations, I came to the conclusion that the error occurs precisely when the `createPair()` function is called.

Please respond if you have experienced something like this. Or have solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved when I changed the wallet to one with more ETH (at least twice the amount that needs to be paid for fees for the deployment)